# When I make a C plugin for erlang will it take full advantage of the spawning system? Does it block?

Tags: erlang

eg I have a program that eats a lot of CPU. I make a C plugin that can interact with erlang. I spawn 16 threads with SMP +16. Will it give me a similar performance compared to something like pthreads on a multicore? The threads do not need to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"C plugin" is not clearly defined in the erlang context.

Either you are writing a port which basically forks a system process.

Or you are writing a linked in driver which runs in the same context as the Erlang vm.

In both cases you can take advantage of multicore cpu's.  The first case just relies on the OS to place the OS processes on different CPU's (which any decent SMP OS should be capable of).

In the second case I'm not so sure but I would expect the drivers to run on different CPU cores also.  Unless you have a strong cause for using linked drivers and you know exactly what you are doing I recommend against them for complexity and stability reasons.  If a port crashes Erlang is notified and can restart it or take other precautions.  If a driver crashes the whole Erlang vm is taken down hard.

The main question is what part of the problem you want to solve in Erlang, if you use erlang only to start your "plugins" this can be much easier be solved just starting processes from the shell, since your "threads" don't need to communicate, why not pass the parameters on the commandline and fork working processes from a shell script?

Comment: You can also be writing a NIF.